# Steampunk novel with mechanical animals, such as dogs?

Tags: story-identification, novel, steampunk

I am trying to remember an old steampunk novel set in perhaps Victorian times. I only remember a few parts of the novel, but a specific part that stands out to me is that the police/detectives/maybe the upper class have mechanical dogs that they are somehow connected to, like companions but they understand them. I believe one of the characters had an aggressive mechanical/robotic wolf.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/l7de7v/steampunk_book_with_mechanical_dogsanimals/

Comment: If so, https://smile.amazon.com/Leviathan-Trilogy-Scott-Westerfeld/dp/1416971742 has been posited as an answer.